# RethinkDB GetNearest and Filter for Multi-Index

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, reql

Is it possible to query nearby point that match with one or more tags?
This is the data that I have:

```
r.db("test").table("Member"):

{ "POSTALCODE":  "526494" ,
"lat":  "1.3640" , "lon":  "103.9531" ,
"memberId":  "22b99a77-5f73-4331-a5da-dcdc46a4b4e7" ,
"membertags": ["tag1" ,"tag2" , "tag3" ] ,
"point": { "$reql_type$":  "GEOMETRY" , "coordinates": [103.9531 ,1.364],"type":  "Point"}
} {
"POSTALCODE":  "525842" ,
"lat":  "1.3516" , "lon":  "103.9384" ,
"memberId":  "79844285-7781-4bd4-819e-db54f90b8c8d" ,
"membertags": ["tag2" ,"tag3" ,"tag4" ,"tag5"] ,
"point": {"$reql_type$":  "GEOMETRY" ,"coordinates": [103.9384 ,1.3516] ,"type":  "Point" }
}
```

As highlighted in [How do I run a filter on a getNearest() query in RethinkDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255750/how-do-i-run-a-filter-on-a-getnearest-query-in-rethinkdb), I could filter getNearest using `eq`

```
var point = r.point(103.9531,1.364);  
r.db('test')
.table('Member')
.getNearest(point, {index: 'point', unit :'km'})
.filter(function(user) {
   return user('doc')('POSTALCODE').eq('525842') //1 RESULT
   //return user('doc')('membertags').eq('tag2') //EMPTY RESULT
})
```

but I could not get the result for multi-indexes (e.g. membertags) as suggested in [rethinkdb with filter and getNearest commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730916/rethinkdb-with-filter-and-genearest-commands) (Option #1) - using `.filter({membertags : 'tag2'})`.

The secondary index was created using `r.db("test").table("Member").index_create("membertags", multi=True)`. I'm aware that filter does not support secondary index, but could not find alternative solution that uses getNearest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can sacrifice performance to use `filter` instead of index, we can do this:

```
var point = r.point(103.9531,1.364);  
r.db('test')
.table('Member')
.getNearest(point, {index: 'point', unit :'km'})
.filter(function(user) {
  return user('doc')('membertags').contains('tag2')
})
```

Instead of using `eq` we now use `contains` to filter the result in which `membertags` field contaisn the tag.

Downside is that `filter` doesn't use index so performance maybe not that great.

Comment: Thanks! - I could now extended it to match with either tags using `return user('doc')('membertags').contains(function (tag) {return tag.eq('tag1').or(tag.eq('tag2'));})` (code: http://pastebin.com/vTjChN0z)
But this won't work for `.and` condition (i.e. return each record that match > 1 tags). Do I miss something here?

Comment: `and` will always return false, because a single tags cannot be equal to two values at a time. Inside predicate function, each time, an element of array is pass into the predicate function. Therefore you cannot use it with `and`. A way to check for this is using `setIntersection` like this: `filter(function(user) {
      return user('doc')('membertags').setIntersection(['tag2', 'tag4']).count().eq(2)
    })` setIntersection return values appear in both array, then count the size of result array